# Atiyah-Singer Index Theorem applied to the Laplacian Operator on Riemann Surfaces

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, partial-differential-equations, algebraic-topology, complex-geometry

Does applying the Atiyah-Singer index theorem to the Laplacian operator on a Riemann surface result in any known theorem? What are some interpretations of the analytic and topological indices? (I'm aware they are both 0, but I want to know if that implies anything).

For example, if we use the $\bar{\partial}$ operator, the Atiyah-Singer index theorem gives use the Riemann-Roch theorem, I'm wondering if something similar happens in this case.